# References? -- Coordination Between Groups

Tags: reference-request, behavioral-economics

Can anyone provide references for research that focuses on coordination between groups of decision makers rather than within group coordination with individual decision makers? \

Edits given the questions posted in comments:

1 - I am interested in behavioral/experimental work. 
2 - Coordination/Cooperation between groups within any context. So...could be groups as groups, groups as nations, etc.

Comment: Do you mean behavioral research?

Comment: Coordination between nations?

Comment: @denesp - actually - yes, I would prefer behavioral/experimental work.   Herr K. - Not specifically but yes!